# No tables in intellJi Ulitimate Edition

Tags: sql-server, intellij-idea

Well I'm a student and we work with MS Studio Management.

I don't like the interface and the lousy auto correction so I decided to code in intelliJ which is much better.

I created a database with 3 tables (intelliJ)

I can't see them in the DB, I can't select but they are there (recreating them == error)

when I migrate to Studio-  I can see the DB and the tables
I attach 2 screenshots. can anyone figure out what's happening?
thnx

[image: studio]

[image: intelliJ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to click '0 of 13' link next to 'ex' database and select at least schema 'dbo' to be introspected. Actually you need to do this for each database, also you can select 'all schemas' there instead of picking up one by one. Then you'll be able to see tables in these schemas.